# I can't access my team site,i'm just a beginner here on SharePoint online 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error, site-collection, 404

Any idea as to how i get back to my site is greatly appreciated.When I try to navigate on the link to my site, I'm getting '`404 not found`' response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 not found means couple of thing happen

- Site / URL you are trying to access is deleted. May be someone accidentally deleted it.
- You dont have correct url may be some typo in it.
- Site may be Locked with no access.

I would check with the tenant administrator and see if the Site collection is still their and not locked.

Answer (score 0):

Also check:

- **IIS** if all Web Applications and Sites are running
- check **ping** to URL, that you have correct IP address
- Verify, that **Content Database** is Online in Central Administration (or with PS)
- Try with PowerShell `Get-SPsite https://sharepoint.sp.com` if you are able to get it